# Python subprocess.check_output recieves extra form feed (0x0c) character

Tags: python, windows, svn, subprocess, chromium

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['svn', '--version', '--quiet'], shell=True)
'\x0c1.6.16\r\n'
>>> subprocess.check_output(['svn', '--version', '--quiet'])
'1.6.16\r\n'
```

On Windows, Python 2.7, when `shell=True` is passed to `subprocess.check_output`, I get one extra `\x0c` character. This is not an expected behavior, because it breaks Chromium's gclient.py from depot_tools. It tries to check if svn version is minimum 1.4, and it's surprised by 0x0c. Then everything blows up.

I don't have any idea why this happens and what does it mean. How could I fix this issue? I don't want to start with hacking gclient.py, because it works for everyone else. Googling this issue gave nothing.

Comment: Please run `subprocess.check_output(['svn', '--version', '--quiet'], shell=True)` again. It should have raised a `CalledProcessError`. Did you mean `subprocess.check_output('svn --version --quiet', shell=True)`?

Comment: I suspect you are going to have to patch it temporarily and raise the issue with the module authors or do you mean it works for everyone else that uses windows with Python2.7?

Comment: Level of indirection? Strip "whitespace" from the start before using it? BTW If I do this on Windows 7 using python 2.7 against git, rather than svn, I don't get the extra char.

Comment: @doctorlove I tried to call git from my console and it doesn't work at all. Something is wrong with my cmd. I tried some hacky cmd tutorial lastly, and I didn't notice that now there is something wrong with it. I don't use it very often, other programs worked... I'll try to figure it out.
Thanks guys for all comments.

Comment: I just meant I shelled a proc to find which version of `git` on my machine since I have `git` instead of `svn`. If you don't have git installed, it won't work for you, just like since I don't have svn installed

Comment: @doctorlove I'm not an alien, man. ;) I have git installed.
I've already solved my issue. Check out my answer, if you are interested.
Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded rude, when you said "it" didn't work I misunderstood. Glad you have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After **doctorlove**'s comment, I wanted to check what would `subprocess.check_output(['git', '--version'], shell=True)` return. But it didn't even launch from cmd... Something was wrong.
Then I've removed a registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` that I added a few days ago. Now everything works ok. That key was supposed to handle autorunning a batch script on cmd startup, but for some reason it broke some character-related stuff in cmd.

Comment: Sounds like you had a startup script for your shell that emits a `\x0C` character

Comment: Of course... it now seems so obvious. I don't know how was it possible, because that script wasn't meant to print anything, but that must have been the reason. Thanks!